# Is it possible that GTK or gtksharp on Windows hardcodes the loader DLLs?

Tags: mono, installation, gtk, gtk#

I have just completed my GTK#/Mono application and am preparing to build an installer. (I'm working in .NET Framework 3.5 and the Most recent stable Mono, 2.6.7, which installs Gtk 2.10.0) I would prefer to make the install as local as possible and not force people to go installing GTK# for .NET on their own. I looked at the installer for banshee (http://banshee.fm) to guide me, and I got almost all of the way there. Unfortunately, the PNG resources I had embedded in my application were not loading.

After an hour or so of intimacy with procmon (http://sysinternals.com), I find that the file libpixbufloader-png.dll isn't being loaded. It's being searched for in only one place: c:\program files\GtkSharp\2.12\lib\gtk-2.0\2.10.0\loaders. If I create just that folder tree and stick the file there, it works.

It seems slightly insane that GTK#/GTK would only look in a single hardcoded location for this file -- not even in the folder the application is in. Can someone tell me if a) this is indeed expected behavior, and b) if there's anything I can do about it, short of having my installer make this path itself? I know I can also just spawn out the GTK# installer, but I was hoping to keep all the Mono/GTK stuff local to my installation, to avoid later confusions over versions, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your installer needs to run this at the end:

C:\Program Files\GtkSharp\2.12\bin\gdk-pixbuf-query-loaders.exe

See the Wix for the official Gtk# installer here:

https://github.com/mono/gtk-sharp/blob/gtk-sharp-2-12-branch/msi/unmanaged/unmanaged.wxs

Comment: Well, heck, look at that. I will go mess with that now and vote up when it works! Thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately, the official Gtk# installer has all sorts of inconsistencies when compared to what is actually installed on my Windows box with the most recent GtkSharp. However, the gdk-pixbuf-query-loaders.exe was in fact the right lead. Now my life sucks trying to get that to work with WIx...

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to call the .exe mentioned my *jpobst*, because you can enter *relative* paths into the `gdk-pixbuf.loaders` config file (btw as you see the paths are *not* hard coded).